# Maps.google.com and Google Maps V3 API geocoder gives different results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following address "12635 SCARSDALE ST, SAN ANTONIO, Texas 78217". If I enter this address in maps.google.com, it gives me the correct address. If I use the Google Maps V3 API geocoder ( http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml ), it returns a lat/long in scarsdale dr, Austin, tx( partial match). I used http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html as well and it gets the same results. 
Usually when this happens, it is something in the address( wrong zip code, misspelling etc).

I cannot see what could be wrong here or why the inconsistency. Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Note: Mapquest on the other hand does return the correct lat/long for this address.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you found an error in Google's data. Google has identified this location as "12635 Scarsdale, San Antonio, TX 78217" (note the missing ST portion of the address).

Their API is probably relying on proximity to find the closest match to the data provided (i.e. what is the closest "12635 Scarsdale" to San Antonio, TX)

You could help them (in this instance) by clicking the Send Feedback link in the bottom right corner of the map.